# File browser - scrolling to the bottom or top of the list

Tags: file-browser

Is there a keyboard shortcut that allows you to scroll the file list view to the bottom or top with one click instead of using the mouse wheel? I mean the way the "End" and "Home" buttons work in Windows.
Thx

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Down Arrow to go all the way down, and Ctrl+Up Arrow to go all the way up.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on windows.